# Is there a way to upload a file to sharepoint via access and include metadata programmatically

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, upload, metadata

I am looking to upload a file (this could be an excel file or a pdf i'm yet to decide) to SharePoint Programmatically from access 2016 and include Metadata.

I have an upload process sorted but only to a library that doesn't have Metadata included. Is there a way to do this programmatically via Access 2016

Comment: This might be helpful: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=296929